# Network traffic flow detection using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas `dataframe` containing network traffic of multiple hosts:

```
df = pd.read_csv ( "traffic.csv",skipinitialspace=True,
                                           usecols=['frame.time_epoch','ip.src','ip.dst','tcp.srcport','tcp.dstport','frame.len','tcp.flags','Protocol'],na_filter=False,encoding="utf-8" )

complete = pd.read_csv ( "traffic.csv",skipinitialspace=True,
                                       usecols=['frame.time_epoch','ip.src','ip.dst','tcp.srcport','tcp.dstport','frame.len','tcp.flags','Protocol'],na_filter=False,encoding="utf-8" )
```

I would like to group traffic flow, which `'frame.len'` sign show the direction of packets. To do so, for each host first I set the sign of the 'frame.len' by comparing 'ip.dst' with host IP:

```
complete.loc[(complete['ip.dst'] == hostip[i])  ,'frame.len'] = complete['frame.len'] * -1
```

then I replace the `'ip.src'` and `'tcp.srcport'` with `'ip.dst'` and 'tcp.dstport' and vis verca for incoming packets whose `'frame.len'` get negative value.

```
complete.loc[(complete['frame.len'] < 0),'ip.src'] = df['ip.dst']
complete.loc[(complete['frame.len'] < 0),'ip.dst'] = df['ip.src']
complete.loc[(complete['frame.len'] < 0),'tcp.srcport'] = df['tcp.dstport']
complete.loc[(complete['frame.len'] < 0),'tcp.dstport'] = df['tcp.srcport']
```

and then I group each flow by the following criteria:

```
complete_flow =     
complete.groupby(['ip.src','ip.dst','tcp.srcport','tcp.dstport','Protocol'])
```

Is there a simpler way using pandas `dataframe` features?